# Fetch data on page load in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to fetch data on page load using this code ngOnInit

```
 lists = [];
 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
..
..
 ngOnInit(): void {
    var formData=new FormData();
    formData.append("type",'TYPE_1');
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'api/auth/fetchdata', formData).subscribe(result => 
    {
      this.lists=result;
      },(error) => {
    }); 
     
    }
```

getting this error :

> The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean
> to use the 'any' type instead?   Type 'Object' is missing the
> following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and
> 26 more.ts

Any Solution, Thanks

Comment: Can you `console.log(result)`. It seem `result` is an object and you're trying to assign it to `lists` which is an array

Comment: Check the duplicate and also please read https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response :)